# How to set Janus GridEX column index

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, janus

I use **Janus** component in winForm application. 
Now, I want to set column index of `GridEX` control, so I use below codes to do it:

```
grd.RootTable.Columns("ColumnName").Index = 1
```

or

```
grd.RootTable.Columns("ColumnName").ColumnSet = 1
```

but, both of them are readonly properties. Then I test below codes:

```
grd.RootTable.Columns("ColumnName").ColumnSetRow = 1
```

or

```
grd.RootTable.Columns("ColumnName").ColumnSetColumn = 1
```

but, an exception by below details occurred:

> `ColumnSerRow` or `ColumnSetColumn` property can only be set when the column belongs to a `ColumnSet`

Please help me, how to change columns indexes in janus grid component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `Position` property in `GridExColumn` object. So your codes should be like this:

```
grd.RootTable.Columns("ColumnName").Position = 1
```

Now, The column which is name `ColumnName` moved to index 1